# Get the parent id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parent, attr

I have a bunch of  elements like the following:

```
     <div class="droppableP" id="s-NSW" style="width:78px; height:63px; position: absolute; top: 223px; left: 532px;">  
 <div class="sensible"></div>  
      </div>
```

They all have class droppableP but different id's obviously and I would like to factor the code in this script I am hacking on.  The original script just has a specific selector for each of one of these divs, but the code is all alike except for the id it does things to, which is either the id of the parent or another div with a name that's related to it.     Here is the original code specifically for this div:

```
$("#s-NSW > .sensible").droppable( {  
    accept : "#i-NSW",  
    tolerance : 'intersect',  
    activeClass : 'droppable-active',  
    hoverClass : 'droppable-hover',  
    drop : function() {  
        $('#s-NSW').addClass('s-NSW');  
        $('#s-NSW').addClass('encastrada');  //can't move any more..  
        $('#i-NSW').remove();  
        $('#s-NSW').animate( {  
            opacity: 0.25   
        },200, 'linear');  
        checkWin();  
    }  
 });
```

Here is how I would like to factor so the same code can do all of them and I will eventually do chaining as well and maybe get rid of the inline styles but here is my first go:

```
$(".droppableP > .sensible").droppable( {  
    accept :    "#i" + $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(2),   
    tolerance : 'intersect',  
    activeClass : 'droppable-active',  
    hoverClass : 'droppable-hover',  
    drop : function() {  
  $(this).parent().addClass($(this).parent().attr('id'));  
  $(this).parent().addClass('encastrada');   
  $("#i" + ($this).parent().attr('id').substring(2)).remove();   
  $(this).parent().animate( {  
      opacity: 0.25   
  },200, 'linear');  
  checkWin();  
    }  
});
```

The error I get is:

> `$(this).parent().attr("id")` is undefined

Many thanks.  I have browsed related questions the one I understand that's closest to mine,  turns out they didn't need parent function at all.  I'm kind of a noob so please don't yell at me too hard if this is a stupid question.  and sorry I'm having a horrible time with the format

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log($(this).parent());` ?

Comment: where do I put that in the middle of a literal?

Comment: I can put it in the function I guess.

Comment: Before this line in the second bit: `$(this).parent().addClass($(this).parent().attr('id'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that works:  I needed an each iterator in there.  I think that was the magic bullet.

```
     $(".droppableP > .sensible").each(function() {
        $(this).droppable( {
           accept :    "#i" + $(this).closest('.droppableP').attr('id').substring(1), 
           tolerance : 'intersect',
           activeClass : 'droppable-active',
           hoverClass : 'droppable-hover',
           drop : function() {
               //console.log($(this).closest());
               $(this).closest('.droppableP').addClass($(this).closest('.droppableP').attr('id'));
               $(this).closest('.droppableP').addClass('encastrado');
               $("#i" + $(this).closest('.droppableP').attr('id').substring(1)).remove();
               $(this).closest('.droppableP').animate( {
                     opacity: 0.25 
                  },
                  200, 
                  'linear'
               );
               checkWin();
           }
        }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass each draggable element to your function to process, and return true if your droppable accepts it.

try:

```
$(".droppableP > .sensible").droppable( {  
  accept : function(draggable) { 
    return $(draggable).attr("id") == "i" + $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(1);
},
```

Comment: +1 - @OP: You probably wouldn't want the jquery id selector, `#`, in your test and looking at the strings, you'd want to start with the 2nd character in the string `.substring(1)` rather than the 3rd

Comment: @munch Thanks. I wasn't really paying much attention to the string manipulation, just the methodology. I've edited my answer.

Comment: oops yeah we want to start the substring with the "-" which is char 1 not char 2.  I was thinking it began with # but of course it doesn't.    
I put the "#" in because the snippet that actually works (above) has it.

Comment: This did not work, I am putting the whole thing online.  It is the beginning of a puzzle.  You drag the pieces to where they go.  
http://colleenweb.com/puzz/AU2.html  When a piece gets close to its target it is supposed to:
   assign the the parent the class of its ID (which gives it the bg graphic)
   give it the class encastrada makes it so it cant move
   remove the draggable element
   run a little animation on the newly dropped element.  

The original code can be found at http://www.fernando.com.ar/jquery-puzzle/index.php I'm trying to make it more DRY